# How to delete and output a new string in a text field?

Tags: functional-programming, textfield, elm

I want to clear the text field and want to create a new placeholder when pressing a button. Additionally I want an Increment in the placeholder that counts every new text field that is created (player 1, player 2, player 3, etc.) I tried to use the Increment button from the elm docs. But I get an error:

```
Something is off with the 5th branch of this `case` expression:

78|       model "Player" + 1
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The 5th branch is:

    number

But the type annotation on `update` says it should be:

    Model
```

I tried to create a new string player that adds every time the "+add" button is pressed +1. So with an onClick event + the name(Clear), how it is also done in the docs.

Here is my Elm Code:

```
--imports
...

-- MAIN


main =
  Browser.sandbox { init = init, update = update, view = view }



-- MODEL
type alias Player =
  { player : String
  , strength : Int
  , number : Int
  }


type alias Model =
  { content : String
  , teams : List Player
  , currentNumber : Int
  , currentPlayer : String
  , currentStrength : Int
  }





init : Model
init =
  { content = ""
  , teams = []
  , currentNumber = 0
  , currentPlayer = ""
  , currentStrength = 0
   }



-- UPDATE


type Msg
  = Change String
  | Clear



update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    Change newContent ->
      { model | content = newContent }

    Clear ->
      model "Player" + 1

-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
  div []
    [ h1 [style "font-family" "impact"] [ text "Team Creator" ]
    ,  h2 [style "font-family" "impact"] [ text "Name and Strength:" ]
    , div[] [ input [ placeholder  " Player 1", style "width" "300px"] [] ]
    , input [ placeholder  " Strength", style "width" "300px"] []
    , div [] [ button [ style "background-color" "#66cc81", style "color" "white", onClick Clear] [ text "+ADD" ] ]
    ,  h2 [style "font-family" "impact"] [ text "Teams:" ]
    , div [] [ text (model.currentPlayer)]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, you are returning a type `String` from a function that returns `Model` by its type signature. The problem is this line

```
  Clear ->
    model "Player" + 1
```

It is a bit unclear what this is supposed to do, but in the case expression above, the code creates a new model where it makes the update `content = newContent`. If you want to update some other field in the model, you need a similar pattern. For example (not 100% sure about the syntax, but you'll hopefully get the idea)

```
  Clear ->
    { model | currentNumber = currentNumber + 1 }
```

Comment: But wouldn't this approach just increment a number? Thats what I need but I want to mix it with the string "player" in front of the number.

Comment: Yes, it only increments the number. As I said, I am not certain what you want to achieve and thus gave that code just as an example. If you wish to update a field that is of type string, you can set the value in similar manner. Note that you cannot concatenate types `String` and `Int` together directly in Elm. It requires a conversion, like `"Hello " ++ "World" ++ String.fromInt 1`